pfSense raw firewall logs
I am looking at a GRE attack agains my system (https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-20946), my entry looks like this:
4,,,1000000103,mvneta0,match,block,in,4,0x0,,50,50087,0,DF,47,gre,1090,59.127.81.214,192.168.2.11,datalength=1070

I can see that IP 59.127.81.214 is probing the sytem, I just do not know the other fields is there any documentation, https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/monitoring/logs/raw-filter-format.html doesn't show any.
